# My implementation of a memmem() like function

Tags: c

Since `memmem()` isn't cross-platform, I'm trying to rewrite it from scratch. How does this look?

```
#define MemContainsStr(Str, StrLen, Substr) MemContainsMem(Str, StrLen, SubStr, sizeof(SubStr))
void *MemContainsMem(const void *StrStart, register unsigned long StrLen, const char *Substr, register const unsigned char SubstrLen) {
    if (StrLen < SubstrLen) {
        return 0;
    }
    register const unsigned char *Str = memchr(StrStart, *Substr, StrLen);
    do {
        if (!Str || StrLen < SubstrLen) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (!memcmp(Str, Substr, SubstrLen)) {
            return Str;
        }
        register void *NewStr = memchr(Str+1, *Substr, StrLen);
        StrLen -= NewStr-Str;
        Str = NewStr;
    } while (Str);
    return 0;
}
```

Are there `register` variables that shouldn't be, how can I further optimize this code?

Comment: As `memmem()` is not a standard C library function, post a reference to the code's functionality.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica [`man memmem()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memmem)

Comment: To actually write this efficiently/library-quality is not trivial. It boils down to using the systems maximum data width efficiently, something the memchr and memcmp supposedly does internally. Your function might need to wiggle around stray bytes that aren't aligned though. You can peek at the [memmem implementation inside libc](https://github.com/walac/glibc/blob/master/string/memmem.c), it's quite complicated.

Comment: "Are there register variables that shouldn't be?" Yes, `register` variables shouldn't be - don't use this identifier at all. It is an obsolete remain from the past, when compilers were very bad at optimizing code. Nowadays, they do a _much_ better job than the programmer when it comes to determining what should be placed inside a register. In particular, the compiler knows everything about the function calling convention and may utilize the fact that some parameters are already in registers when the function is entered.

Comment: @Lundin There isn't a way to know how complicated it is, without `two_way_short/long_needle()`. Where is `#include "str-two-way.h"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to rewrite it from scratch. How does this look?

**Mis-matched function signature**

OP code uses

```
void *MemContainsMem(const void *StrStart, register unsigned long StrLen, 
    const char *Substr, register const unsigned char SubstrLen);
```

The [referenced code](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memmem) uses

```
void *memmem(const void *haystack, size_t haystacklen, 
    const void *needle, size_t needlelen);
```

Recommend to use the same function signature.  Unclear why OP changed from `size_t` to `unsigned long` and changed pointer type.

Use of `Str...` hints at a *string*, yet this function does not operate on *strings*.  Maybe `Mem...`?  Hard to beat the names `needle/haystack`.

**Invalid access in corner case**

The first `*Substr` in `memchr(StrStart, *Substr, StrLen);` is UB when `SubstrLen` is 0.

Code should gracefully and correctly  handle `SubstrLen == 0` and `SubLen == 0` cases.

**`register`**

`register` is a good keyword to use when the rare programmer better understands the compilation situation better than the compiler.  For the other 99.99% of us, drop `register` and let the compiler do its job.  Do not tie the hands of the compiler.

**`0` vs. `NULL`**

Minor: Since the return type is a pointer, consider returning `NULL` rather than `0` as being more idiomatic.  Either works.

**Unneeded code**

The first `if (StrLen < SubstrLen) { return 0;`  appears unnecessary as that case is detected in later code.

**Redundant test**

`} while (Str);` can be replaced with `} while (1);`.  Alternatively make loop a `while()`

```
//register const unsigned char *Str = memchr(StrStart, *Substr, StrLen);
//do {
//    if (!Str || StrLen < SubstrLen) {
//        return 0;
//    }

const unsigned char *Str;
while ((Str = memchr(StrStart, *Substr, StrLen)) != NULL && (StrLen >= SubstrLen)) {
```

**Invalid pointer subtraction**

Not portable to subtract `void *` in `NewStr-Str`.  Use `unsigned char *NewStr` instead.

**Array or *string***

The define treats `Substr` as an array and not a *string*.
Good macro practice uses a `()` arround each parmeter.

```
// #define MemContainsStr(Str, StrLen, Substr) \
//    MemContainsMem(Str, StrLen, SubStr, sizeof(SubStr))

#define MemContainsStr(Str, StrLen, Substr) \
    MemContainsMem((Str), (StrLen), (SubStr), strlen(SubStr))
```

Be wary now of double evaluation of `SubStr`

---

> Are there register variables that shouldn't be, how can I further optimize this code?

I recommend to drop all `register` usages and simple enable greater compiler optimizations levels.

A fundamental weakness to this code is that it is O(m*n) where `m, n` are the lengths of the needle and haystack.

Better algorithms are `O(m+n)` and oblige significant code changes.

---

ToDo

**Bug??**

`Str+1` is suspicious in `NewStr = memchr(Str+1, *Substr, StrLen);` as it is not clear that `StrLen > 0` always at this point.  e.g. `StrLen, SubstrLen` both are 0.

Hmmm

Comment: If removing `register` and renaming the variable to `needle`, does that mean that `needle` is now allocated in the stack? :)

Comment: @Lundin Yes, _needle_ is in the _stack_ somewhere - just cannot find it. ;-)

Comment: Feedback for **Array or *string***: I made it treat it like an array, because for this specific implementation, the second argument will always be a array literal.

Comment: @user227432 the name `MemContainsStr()` then mis-leads.  Sounds like to are making a `MemContainsMem()` or `MemContainsArray()`.